# Listing folders inside google drive using php api

Tags: drive, google-drive-realtime-api

I am using google Drive api `($files = $drive->files->listFiles ($parameters))` and it seems to return files that are not in folders, how can I access folders and their children and so of.

Answer (score 0):

[Files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) returns all files that's contained in your Drive API folder including those within subfolders. I've tried it myself. What maybe happening to you is that you have many files and for you to access the file, you need to use nextPageToken. And make sure you set the pageSize to 50 to display more files at a time.